# Why are not all exported functions recognized by TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following code:

**authPopup.ts**

```js
import { msal, consentScopes } from 'src/services/auth/authIndex'

export const getAccount = () => msal.getAccount()
export const loginPopup = () => msal.loginPopup(consentScopes)
export const logout = () => {
  msal.logout()
}
export const getTokenPopup = (request) => {
  return msal
    .acquireTokenSilent(request)
    .catch(() => msal.acquireTokenPopup(request))
}
```

**authRedirect**

```js
import { msal, consentScopes } from 'src/services/auth/authIndex'

export const getAccount = () => msal.getAccount()
export const loginRedirect = () => {
  msal.loginRedirect(consentScopes)
}
export const logout = () => {
  msal.logout()
}
export const getTokenRedirect = (request, endpoint?: string) => {
  return msal
    .acquireTokenSilent(request, endpoint)
    .catch(() => msal.acquireTokenRedirect(request)) // page reload
}
```

**authService.ts**

```js
import { Screen } from 'quasar'
import { isInternetExplorer } from 'src/services/utils/utilsService'
import * as authPopup from 'src/services/auth/authPopup'
import * as authRedirect from 'src/services/auth/authRedirect'

const loginMethod = Screen.lt.sm || isInternetExplorer ? 'redirect' : 'popup'

export const auth = (loginMethod === 'popup')
  ? { loginMethod, ...authPopup }
  : { loginMethod, ...authRedirect }
```

**useAccounts.ts**

```js
import { auth } from 'src/services/auth/authService'

auth.getAccount  // works fine, no TS error
auth.loginPopup  // works fine, with TS error that it can't be found
```

Why is the method `loginPopup` not recognised by TypeScript in the file `useAccount.ts`? The thrown error is:

> TS2339: Property 'loginPopup' does not exist on type '{ getAccount: ()
>   => Account; loginPopup: () => Promise; }'.

Visible in `useAccounts.ts`:

[image]

Visible in `authService.ts`:

[image]

When looking in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) I assume this is because it has another `function signature` because the wrapping function doesn't need an argument. How would this be resolved? Do we need to declare a new `interface` and how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Altering an export on runtime information sounds like a bad idea to begin with…

Comment: Show what `authPopup` and `authRedirect` look like

Comment: It is a bad idea, but the type error isn't because of that.

Comment: You don't know the screen size at compile time, so your module can't selectively export just one or the other method based on information not available at compile time. The module must export both, and the decision which method to call needs to be made somewhere else.

Comment: We use Vue.js and the Quasar Framework. This code can correctly detect the screen size and represent the correct logon method. Updated OP.

Comment: "*Property 'loginPopup' does not exist on type '{ … loginPopup: () => Promise; }'.*" doesn't really make sense

Comment: Like @deceze said, your `authRedirect` module does not export a `loginPopup` method, so that's why you cannot access it. Your conditional operator only can be useful if both modules implemented (exported) the same interface.

Comment: You can find the complete code [here](https://github.com/DarkLite1/hip/tree/master/src/services/auth). But nonetheless it works correctly, only TS can't find it.

Comment: `loginPopup` is only defined by one of the ternary branches. That's why it errors. This code is _really_ abusing modules by the way. Just use object literals instead of namespace imports.

Comment: Thank you @AluanHaddad but I'm new to javaScript and TS. Could you give an example on the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you spread all the functions in your authService in your auth constant a new object of type any is exported. So you need to specify what `auth` from `authService` is

If you have the same function names. why do you have two different files.

```js
const auth: () => {
    getAccount: () => boolean;
    loginPopup: () => boolean;
    logout: () => boolean;
    getTokenPopup: () => boolean;
    loginMethod: string;
} | {
    getAccount: () => boolean;
    loginRedirect: () => boolean;
    logout: () => boolean;
    getTokenRedirect: () => boolean;
    loginMethod: string;
}
```

Ignore the `=> boolean` I had to see the problem with my eyes you can have one single file.

```js
function loginMethod () {
    // validation to see if it is IE
    return  true || true ? 'redirect' : 'popup'
}

export const getAccount = () => {
   if (loginMethod()) {
   /// do things
   }
   // else things
}
export const login = () => {
   if (loginMethod()) {
   /// do things
   }
   // else things
}
export const logout = () => {
   if (loginMethod()) {
   /// do things
   }
   // else things
}
export const getTokenRedirect = () => {
   if (loginMethod()) {
   /// do things
   }
   // else things
}
```

Comment: Look at the screenshot I added. This is not it, why are the other methods still visible and only `loginPopup` is not?

Comment: Nope, is not just `loginPopup` but instead all the functions from `authPopup` that are missing

Comment: As you are using vscode hover the mouse over `export const auth =` exactly at the word auth and I’ll show you the problem

Comment: Updated OP with the picture you requested

Comment: Thank you @Ernesto but in the meantime I totally wend with one file to KISS. I'm still learning so it's with falling and standing up again. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.